# How to write a googletest testcase for functions returning void and void *?

Tags: function, void, googletest

I'm trying to test functions returning void and void* using googletest. I'm just a beginner and I have just used EXPECT till now to test the code.

Please let me know how to write test cases for void and void * functions.

A sample code would help a lot. :)

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more specific about the function(s) needing tested.  Can you give concrete examples of the functions?

Comment: Any generic example would help me to go forward :) 
later I can use that example to learn and implement in my code.
thanks

Comment: void add(int a, int b){
 global_sum = a+b;
}

Comment: void add(int a, int b){

 global_sum = a+b;

}
how can we test this when it is not returning any value. 
All i want is to test a function which does not return anything. In this case we cant use Expect_EQ or any Expect_* for testing.

Comment: I think the bigger lesson is, if you have a void function, it probably has an observable postcondition.  That is, it changes the state of some object or variable. In testing, you should call the function, then make assertions (with EXPECT_EQ, EXPECT_TRUE, etc) about the postconditions.

Comment: I have a void function that either exits or not as its observable behaviour. I can EXPECT_EXIT but how do I not EXPECT_EXIT?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example with your `Add` function, and also with a throwing `Divide` function:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int global_sum(0), global_quotient(0);

void Add(int a, int b) {
  global_sum = a + b;
}

void Divide(int numerator, int divisor) {
  if (divisor == 0)
    throw std::logic_error("Can't divide by 0.");
  global_quotient = numerator / divisor;
}

TEST(Calculator, Add) {
  EXPECT_EQ(0, global_sum);

  Add(1, 2);
  EXPECT_EQ(3, global_sum);

  Add(-1, 1);
  EXPECT_EQ(0, global_sum);
}

TEST(Calculator, Divide) {
  EXPECT_EQ(0, global_quotient);

  EXPECT_NO_THROW(Divide(2, 1));
  EXPECT_EQ(2, global_quotient);

  EXPECT_THROW(Divide(1, 0), std::logic_error);
  EXPECT_EQ(2, global_quotient);

  EXPECT_NO_THROW(Divide(1, 2));
  EXPECT_EQ(0, global_quotient);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: This is not a direct test of the function to be void, something like `EXPECT_EQ(Add, void)`. It only tests indirect the side effects of the functions but how to test e.g. `void myfunction(void)`?